# Issue with MediaMessageStream.getStreamPosition()

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

When I share video from my Android application to TV via ChromeCast device.
I have a thread to get the current stream position every second to update the current time of the video on my application.
`double position = messageStream.getStreamPosition();`
But sometimes this function returns the same value in some seconds. So my app can't display it continuously.

This is what I logged:

```
11-07 14:41:36.567: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 587.3914184570313
11-07 14:41:36.637: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 587.3914184570313
11-07 14:41:37.638: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 587.3914184570313
11-07 14:41:38.639: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 587.3914184570313
11-07 14:41:39.640: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 587.3914184570313
11-07 14:41:40.641: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 587.3914184570313
11-07 14:41:41.652: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 588.5733334960937
11-07 14:41:42.663: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 589.5793334960938
11-07 14:41:43.664: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 590.5843334960938
11-07 14:41:44.665: E/CastPlayerActivity(27190): position 591.5893334960938
```

Does anyone know why it returns the same value sometimes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaProtocolMessageStream stores the current position in a local variable.  This variable is updated when the Chromecast receiver sends a RAMP update command to the sender.  It's possible your receiver is not sending out updates as frequently as you are polling it.  You can check to see how often you are receiving an update by extending MediaProtocolMessageStream and overriding onStatusUpdated().

```
public class CustomMediaProtocolMessageStream extends MediaProtocolMessageStream {

    protected void onStatusUpdated() {
        Log.d(TAG, "I was updated!");
    }
}
```

If this is the case, modify the receiver to send out status updates more often.  You can also request that the receiver update it's status by calling MediaProtocolMessageStream.requestStatus() and waiting for the command to complete.

```
MediaProtocolCommand cmd = mMessageStream.requestStatus();
cmd.setListener(new MediaProtocolCommand.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(MediaProtocolCommand mPCommand) {
        Log.d(TAG, "My status should be updated.");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(MediaProtocolCommand mPCommand) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

messageStream.getcurrentposition();

Comment: Sr. I don't see getCurrentPossition() function in MediaProtocolMessageStream API

Comment: it is method in simple media player